# TypeError: decoding str is not supported (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, string, utf-8, decode, utf-16

I am receiving a strange error when trying to turn a bytes object into a string:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Scraper_v1.0.py", line 149, in <module>
    rawjsonstr = str(rawjsonstr, 'utf-16')
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

My code is as follows:

```
# preparing string
            try:
                rawjsonstr = "".join(rawjson[3]).encode('utf-16')  # used to select the correct text/javascript node
            except IndexError:
                errorcount += 1
                with open(filepath, "at") as f:
                    write = csv.writer(f)
                    write.writerow(["Error: no valid JSON found",
                                    statenum,
                                    statesubnum,
                                    suburbnum,
                                    listingnum,
                                    listingsurlstr])
            pass

            rmvlist = ["var digitalData = ",
                        "var titanEnabled = true;",
                        "titan = titan || {};",
                        "// enable the command queue to allow spa execution in the correct order",
                        "titan.cmd = titan.cmd || [];"]

            rawjsonstr = str(rawjsonstr, 'utf-16')
```

**Edit**

Re-ran the above code without encoding/decoding. Now receive the following error on the same loop.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/isaac/PycharmProjects/ResidentialData/AllHomesScraper_v1.0.py", line 162, in <module>
    jsondata = json.loads(rawjsonstr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1033 (char 1032)
```

I will re-run it and capture the string that is causing this failure (looks like it's just incorrectly formatted JSON data).

Comment: Wait, why are you encoding the string and then immediately decoding it? It seems like you probably left something out that makes `rawjsonstr` a `str` instance instead of a `bytes` instance when execution hits `str(rawjsonstr, 'utf-16')`.

Comment: This does not make sense. encoding and decoding is silly, but it should work by definition. If you `encode`-ed with UTF-16, then decoded the same data with UTF-16, then it should round trip with no problems. If you can reproduce, wrap the `str(rawjsonstr, 'utf-16')` in a `try/except` and print do a `print(type(rawjsonstr), repr(rawjsonstr))` to see what it failing. I'm assuming you left out critical code, but if not, we need more info to determine the problem.

Comment: The code was originally written in Python 2.7. I migrated to the 3.4 interpreter and ran into several issues around the bytes/string format changes. I then used trial and error with different encode/decode combinations until it worked, hence why this may seem strange.

I will use the try/except wrapper to try and pinpoint what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that generates this error? `rawjsonstr = "".join(rawjson[3]).encode('utf-16')` should generate a `bytes` object. When passed to `rawjsonstr = str(rawjsonstr, 'utf-16')`, it should work. Please provide a better code sample

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I have updated the original question with the complete block of code.

Edit: The code appears to run without encoding and decoding the string. Will update if the error persists on the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error was being caused as a result of the program trying to parse an invalid JSON string: [JSON formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTA9n.png)

**Solution:** Catch the error and append a '{' to the end of the string when it occurs.